# Is "Get it me" a grammatically correct sentence?

Tags: complementation

A friend of mine was telling me he was hungry and so I said he should get food. He then said "but you're not here to get it me". At this point I told him that it didn't sound like an actual correct sentence but he argued it was. I tried to tell him how weird it sounded but he just said that since he's the British one and I'm Swedish, he'd know the language better than me. So is it actually a legit working sentence or not?

Comment: Can you explain what your friend meant by the phrase "to get it me"?  Did he mean *to bring him to the food* or *to bring the food to him* or something else about which I can't even guess?

Comment: It's entirely possible that it's a legit slang phrase from where he lives in Britain.  It would get you funny looks if you said it here in Southern California.

Comment: He meant it in the way that he wanted me to go get the food for him and give it to him.

Comment: This wouldn't be grammatical or a widely familiar slang phrase in AsE. If I heard this in the U.S. I would assume that it was a foreign speaker -- or perhaps a subculture that I didn't know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This construction is, I think, restricted to British English (and possibly British-derived Englishes—I don't know what Ozzies and other colonials say). I can't remember ever hearing it (or the parallel *Give it me*) in the US; we'd say "You're not here to get it for me".

What's involved here is actually a collision between two 'rules'.

- The first is that a semantic Recipient cast as a nominal indirect object rather than as the oblique of a preposition is supposed to lie between the verb and the semantic Received, the direct object—it's that sequence that informs the hearer/reader which nominal is the indirect object and which the direct object.

  > Get/give Joe a sandwich, *not* *Get/give a sandwich Joe.
- The second is that the 'new information' in the construction should occupy the *last*, stressed place in the clause. Consequently, if it is the Recipient which is the new information, it will follow the Received and be cast as the oblique of the appropriate preposition.

  > Get a sandwich for **Joe** (not Sam).
  >   Give the sandwich to **Joe** (not Sam).

But in your example, neither the Recipient nor the Received is new information—not only in this particular context but virtually by definition, since both are expressed as pronouns—and neither should occupy the stressed position.

So whaddaya do?

If you're American, you might just say *Gimme* (or, more minatorily, *Give*); but that's usually too peremptory for civil conversation. So we compromise: we use the oblique construction, but emphasize the verb and put secondary stress on the preposition, which de-stresses both pronouns.

> You're not here to **get** it *for* me.

But BrE speakers have the option of employing the object construction, with no emphasis on either pronoun: everything falls away from the verb.

> **Get** me <sub>it</sub>. *or*
>   **Get** it <sub>me</sub>

If it makes you feel any better, it sounds just as odd to me as to you; but us foreigners don't get a vote.

Comment: In colloquial BrE, ***Give it me*** is quite common, and I wouldn't normally pay it any attention unless the speaker didn't seem like the kind of person who'd normally use such a highly idiomatic construction. But I don't think there would be many if any speakers who'd use ***Get it me*** to ask for something. But I speak as one [who disagrees with John Lawler](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/90531/2637) on the limits of acceptable usage in this area, so what do I know?

Comment: (The fact of the "misplaced" indirect object being a *pronoun* is definitely significant though. No-one says, for example, *Why don't you give it John?* except in some weird context like *The monster is demanding a human sacrifice! Why don't we give it John?)*

Comment: @FumbleFingers Oops, I left off the relevant example--fixed now. But yeah, *get it me* still sounds odd to me even in transatlantic mode; I think it's the *give* construction transferred, licensed by being an embedded clause.

Comment: Maybe us Brits are particularly prone to play fast and loose with /t/ and neutral vowels. I'm sure we use far more glottal stops, and once you've committed to ending ***it*** with ***ʔ***, it's both logically and anatomically awkward to continue with a "real" /t/ for ***to***. To a typical lazy speaker such as me, the easiest way to deal with that is to just "swallow" the schwa too - effectively, underenunciating the word to the point where it simply disappears (which we then hear so often it ends up sounding "grammatical" anyway).

Comment: @FumbleFingers Yous guys also have a much wider variety of stresses to play with than we do. General American speakers use a pitch range of about a third; the first thing you learn as an actor dealing with RP accents is expand that to a sixth.

Comment: Fascinating! I didn't know that before, but as soon as I read it I thought *That does seem to accord with my perceptions*. Until relatively recently, much of my exposure to spoken AmE had actually been from relatively low-grade "entertainment / trivia for the masses", and I therefore tended to associate AmE accents with attention-grabbing "bread and circuses" contexts. Now I listen to quite a lot of "serious" talks / discussions on Youtube, and it often seems to me the BrE speakers have a more pronounced "lilt" even in "relaxed" contexts.

Comment: ...apropos which I just watched [this Youtube clip](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qnGNfz7JiZ8) about creating a new "voice" for Google speech output last night. It's fascinating to see how carefully they build their database of "phones". So each "phoneme" may have a range of "alleles" with different characteristics in terms of absolute pitch, rising/falling intonation, etc. And the software that stitches them all together to construct complete utterances just gets better and better.